# Group several rows of data into one row by column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result of a query that looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to write a query that will take the `relationshipdescriptions` from the above query and group them by person? For example:

1. GUID1     Son, Spouse
2. GUID2     Son
3. GUID3     Aunt, Mother

I will be using this query in a CTE so I will not be able to use variables.

SQL Server 15.0.2

Comment: What SQL Server version used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select personguid, string_agg(relationshipdescription, ',')
from t
group by personguid;
```